# problem with mat-error of many input inside table in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I have an application built in angular 6. I use many inputs inside a table. the problem is when I use `mat-error` to detect if user enter data all inputs mark as required and when user enter data to one of them the required message disappear from all inputs

```html
     <ng-container matColumnDef="documents_administrative_orders_num">
              <th class="text-center" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{objLang.arrLang.doc_num}}</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let idx = index   ">
                   <!-- {{element.documents_administrative_orders_num}}  -->
                  <mat-form-field dir="ltr" lang="en">
                    <input matInput [formControl]="element.documents_administrative_orders_num"  >
                    <mat-error *ngIf="element.documents_administrative_orders_num.hasError('required')">
                            Field is <strong>required</strong>
                    </mat-error>
                  </mat-form-field>
                </td>
            </ng-container>
```

I am using material design

Answer (score 0):

You can try your code in this way. If you use the **ngModel** then you can give error for that particular input.

```
<form class="example-form" #actionGroupMasterForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(actionGroupMasterForm)">
   <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input matInput placeholder="Action Group" name="action group" id="actionGroup" required #actionGroups=ngModel [(ngModel)]="actionGroup">
        <mat-error *ngIf="actionGroups.invalid && (actionGroups.dirty || actionGroups.touched)">
          {{getErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>
   </mat-form-field>
   <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input matInput placeholder="Action Group Name" name="action group name" id="actionGroupName" required #actionGroupNames=ngModel
          [(ngModel)]="actionGroupName">
        <mat-error *ngIf="actionGroupNames.invalid && (actionGroupNames.dirty || actionGroupNames.touched)">
          {{getErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>
   </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you show me your code in codesandbox or something, so that I can look into it.

Comment: thank you. I resolve my problem by HTML table and  I will post the code here when I finish resolve it by material design table

Comment: Ok, No problem.

Comment: Hey you said you will be sending the code. I am working on that too. I need to see that code.